# How to save the Primary key and the value for a form submit

Tags: coldfusion

I have a series of table rows like this:

```
<cfloop query="qryPlayer">
   (...snip...)
   <input data-playerid="#PlayerID#" name="PlayerSort" value="#PlayerSort#">
   (...snip...)
</cfloop>
```

At the bottom of the form, I have a single field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="PlayerIDs"> <!--- Populated by js --->
```

Whenever the user changes a value in any row, I populate PlayerIDs with a list of the primary keys associated with the fields that needs to be updated:

```
$('input[name=PlayerSort]').change(function() {
    $('input[name=Save]').show();
    var arrPlayerID = [];
    $('input[name=PlayerSort]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val()) {
            arrPlayerID.push($(this).data('playerid'));
        }
    });
    $('input[name=PlayerIDs]').val(arrPlayerID.join(','));
});
```

Then when the user presses the Save button, I update all the fields that have values in them.

Q: Is that the right thing for me to be doing?  It works, but have I forgotten some fundamental way of handling a form submit?

BTW, the client doesn't want it to be AJAXified because he wants to give the user the ability to press reset and start over again.  So, enter a bunch of values, click Save, and have ColdFusion update all the PlayerSort values associated with form.PlayerIDs.

```
<cfloop list="#form.PlayerIDs#" index="local.PlayerID">
   <cfset local.Index = local.Index + 1>
   UPDATE dbo.Player SET
   PlayerSort = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ListGetAt(form.PlayerSort,local.Index)#">
   WHERE PlayerID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#local.PlayerID#">;
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is fine. It could, however, be done without JavaScript which would reduce and simplify your code a bit as well as ensure it works on the odd chance that the user has JavaScript disabled.

Use this for your form code:

```
 <cfloop query="qryPlayer">
    (...snip...)
    <input name="PlayerSort_#PlayerID#" value="#PlayerSort#">
    (...snip...)
 </cfloop>
```

Then your action code would be this:

```
 <cfloop collection="#Form#" item="field">
    <cfif ListLen(field,"_") IS 2 AND ListFirst(field,"_") IS "PlayerSort">
        <cfquery datasource="YourDatasource">
        UPDATE  dbo.Player
        SET     PlayerSort = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Form[field]#">
        WHERE   PlayerID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ListLast(field,'_')#">
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
 </cfloop>
```

Comment: Thanks Steve!  I thought I was forgetting something!